# Wireless Charging stopped working; Could it be a software issue? (Samsung Galaxy S3)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-3, charging, wireless-charging, samsung-droid-charge

I've had a Samsung Galaxy S3 for a few years,  I even upgraded to a newer model, and revered back to my trusty ol' S3 because I missed it, and was and was happy with it's size & features.

Eventually the USB charge port stopped working (a common problem on this model).  Replacement part is under $2 but microsoldering & board repair are beyond my skill level, so I got a 2nd battery + external charger, which I've been swapping out twice a day for six months.

It's a bit of a pain, so when I realized ***Qi-style Wireless Charging*** could be inexpensively "retrofit" to my device, I was thrilled!

The transmitter & receiver pad arrived yesterday. I placed the pad under the battery cover as instructed (touching the previously-mysterious 2nd set of charging contacts), put it on the transmitter, and *voilà*, my charging headaches were solved!  It charged faster than plugging it in [used to], and even worked with my rubber case attached.

**Hooray!**  *Until the next day.*  **:-(**

Today the phone does not detect the wireless charger.  I've tried restarting the phone repeatedly, tried two batteries on each of two receiver pads (they accidentally sent 2 instead of 1), tried with/without case & cover, and even different power sources & cables to the transmitter.

**None of these steps worked which leads me to believe this is a software problem... Is that possible?**

If I can't get it working I'm obviously going to send the parts back and go back to constantly swapping batteries but I'm hoping someone has a suggestion.  Could there be settings I am unaware of?

When working, *[Ampere Meter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=zaka.com.amperemeter&hl=en)* app said it was charging wirelessly at 1050mA.  Receiver pads are rated for 800Ma; Batteries are 3.87v/7.98/Wh/2100mAh.  As I recall it would charge around 650mA back when the charge port worked.

<sub>Photo is similar receiver pad, on same model of phone:</sub>

[image: Wireless Charging Receiver Pad Installation on Samsung Galaxy S3]

```
Samsung Galaxy S3, rooted (with no other issues), running Kitkat 4.4.4.
```

- Link to [Samsung Wireless Charging Support](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00047798/).

Comment: Couldn't you just take your phone to a service centre?

Comment: Warranty was gone a long time ago.  The goal is to not spend any money, and to keep my existing phone.  After  trying all the hardware combinations I could think of, I was hoping there might be something software-related I could try.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, my receiver (NillKin) stopped charging the phone on the same day as yours did.  I have a Pixel XL (Android 8) & this solution worked great!  ...until it didn't.  Try turning the phone off & see if it will charge. Mine still will, but only if turned off.  I do notice that I have to be more precise with placing it on the pad than I used to.  Only thing I can think of electrically that matches the symptoms would be if there are multiple wires used in the loop & one is either shorted or ground.  ???  Anyway, I ordered another one that should be here in a couple of days.